# Generate footprint for IC

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, altium, footprint

I am designing PCB and schematic in Altium Designer. I need to add [this IC](http://www.ti.com/product/CC3220MOD/description) to board design. TI does not provide any libraries and Altium files containing this IC. But in data sheet there's information about footprint:
`LGA Package
– 1.27-mm Pitch, 63-Pin, 20.5-mm × 17.5-mm LGA Package for Easy Assembly and Low-Cost PCB Design`

Maybe I can generate this footprint somewhere for Altium?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: How to generate footprint in Altium Designer using information I have

Comment: Pages 85-87 of the datasheet show the package measurements, recommended land pattern, and recommended paste. That is all the information you need to make a footprint. When it is released, you may be able to use the design files from the corresponding launchpad, but it does not appear to be public yet.

Answer (score 3):

A while back I created a [tutorial on adding components to Altium libraries](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-kyY25CGJtM). You will very rarely find pre-made libraries, and personally I don't recommend using them anyway because the varying styles between libraries will lead to a very sloppy design.

The other option is to use the [IPC-Compliant Footprint Wizard](http://www.altium.com/documentation/17.0/display/ADES/FootprintWizard_Dlg-Form_FootprintWizard((IPC+Compliant+Footprint+Wizard))_AD), which can be found in the `Tools` menu. With that tool you can take the values from the datasheet and generate your own footprint for the component.